# Convert string to regex using regexp and test values in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression that is in string form, I want to bind that regex to my grid cell. Such that, now the values in that cell are validated against that regex. I am using `RegExp` JavaScript library for conversion and testing the value. But it is either returning `false` everytime or giving me an `invalid regex`, even for the simplest of the regex used.

This is the method I am using:

```
addCellValidator(columnObj[0].name, new CellValidator({                 
    isValid: function (value) {
        var regex = new RegExp("/^[a-zA-Z\-]+$/");
        return value == "" || (regex.test(value)); 
    }
}));
```

Is it the format or any special pattern required by the `RegExp`?

Comment: what values are you testing against?

Comment: Special characters in this case..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just added the `/` `/` to the string, this works:

> ```
> addCellValidator(columnObj[0].name, new CellValidator({
>                 isValid: function (value) {
>                     var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z\-]+$");
>                     return value == "" || (regex.test(value)); }
>             }));
> ```

Answer (score 6):

While this is valid JavaScript code:

```
new RegExp("/^[a-zA-Z\-]+$/")
```

... it doesn't generate the regular expression you think. It's equivalent to this:

```
/\/^[a-zA-Z-]+$\//
```

You'll have to:

- Strip delimiters
- Extract and parse [flags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_Searching_With_Flags), if any, e.g.:

  ```
  "/^[a-z-]+$/i" ---> new RegExp("^[a-z-]+$", "i")
  ```

One more note: there's no point in escaping `-` with backslash. If want to match a literal `-` inside a character class you need to put it as first or last item.

Comment: Your explanation helped me realize I wasn't parsing the flags, thanks for having a detailed response =)